# Symfony2: Load config-files depending on domain

Tags: php, symfony

At the moment we are running an online-shop for germany. Now we want also offer our products in UK with an own domain.

Depending on the domain their are several settings which should be loaded:

- Google Analytics ID
- Payment API Secrets/Keys, ...
- Currency
- Language
- Admin Mail
- Tracking Pixel (FB)
- and more....

In a previous project we solved it by putting this settings in a domain-table in the database. But I think with the whole payment service information and key and and and.. it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a bundle [Extension class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) to load your configuration depending on the host.

The bundle Extension:

```
// src/AcmeBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeExtension.php

<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AcmeExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $rootdir = $container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');

        // Load the bundle's services.yml
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        // Load parameters depending on current host
        $paramLoader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($rootdir.'/config')); // Access the root config directory
        $parameters = sprintf('parameters_%s.yml', $container->getParameter('router.request_context.host'));

        if (!file_exists($rootdir.'/config/'.$parameters)) {
            $parameters = 'parameters.yml'; // Default
        }

        $paramLoader->load($parameters); 
    }
}
```

The corresponding bundle Configuration:

```
// src/AcmeBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme');

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Like this, you can create a file named `parameters_localhost.yml` and it will be automatically loaded.
If the file is not found, the default `parameters.yml` will be used.

You can apply this logic based on every parameters you want (like `_locale` used for your translations, I guess).

Hope this help.

Comment: Ive added this to my AppBundle. I can access the parameters from the new files. But if I define a key-value-pair in the default config.yml (parameters-tag) and in the parameters_localhost.yml I get the value of the config.yml. But this should only be the fallback config. How can I change the priority? The priority should be (from low to high) config.yml, parameters.yml, parameters_localhost.yml (last overrides all other)

Comment: Do you need to load the default `parameters.yml` in all cases (in addition to the `parameters_[host].yml`) ? If not, remove the default `parameters.yml` from the imports in your `config.yml`. Otherwise, I'll make a quick edit to manage loading order.

Comment: The settings of the database and mailer are independed of the domain. So there would be redundances. The alternative is to dont define the parameters from the parameters_localhost.yml in the parameters.yml file (if there is no better solution).

Comment: I see. I'll make some tries in order to see if we can manage priorities depending on loading order and keep you informed about the best alternative here.

Comment: I've uploaded the version with the new code on the server -> router.request_context.host is still localhost? How can that be?

Comment: Are you browsing the app with your production hostname  (Not localhost) ? If yes, try to remove manually (rm) all in your cache directory. Then, be sure that the loaded parameters doesn't come from your main parameters.yml. It can be part of an ‘imports’ in your config/security.yml . Otherwise, the repository of your project could help me to debug.

Comment: I simply "echo" the router.request_context.host in the Extension-Class. And the result is localhost.. But I will try a litte bit..

Comment: There is already known issues about this parameter is always rendering localhost. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11440  . A workaround : Replace `router.request_context.host` by `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and the file loaded will depends on the value of the `ServerName` of your vhost.

Answer (score 4):

I know that the best answer is already chosen, but I found other approach with `parameters.php`:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

$hostArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$hostArrayCount = count($hostArray);
$host = $hostArray[$hostArrayCount - 2] . '.' . $hostArray[$hostArrayCount - 1];
$hostDir = $container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/config/domains/';
$parameters = sprintf('%s.yml', $host);

if (file_exists($hostDir . $parameters)) {
    $hostParamLoader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($hostDir));
    $hostParamLoader->load($parameters);
}
```

and in `config.yml` after:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

add string:

```
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

Comment: For me this is the best solution because I need these parameters available before loading config files. Only change I would make is how I extract the host name: `$host = array_reverse(explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))[1]` I didn't know I could do this so good tip!

Answer (score 2):

If each of your shop is a different app installation, then why not keep your config in `parameters.yml` file ? You can also take a look at [ParameterHandler](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler) script which will help you manage all parameters.

If you use single code base, maybe you should totally rethink your implementation, because for example, what if in the future you will need to make products from UK shop independent from products in DE shop etc. ? (there are more use cases like that)

I think that your current solution is a short term solution and if you plan to expand to different countries, you should invest some time for a long term solution. Of course it depends all from your requirements and use cases.

An option is splitting your application into channels where each channel will be a shop in UK and DE and so on..

You could then also have a different settings, products, payments, currencies per channel etc..

You could take a look at [Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius) project on GitHub. They developed this nice [ChannelBundle](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusChannelBundle) which you can see how it works.

Comment: At the moment the domains are pointing to the same directory/system. I think splitting the code have definitly several advantages. I don't have any experiences and splitting a system like this. But my problem is, that I dont know how to deploy the code or several parts of the code to different systems without any complications / incompatibilites..

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetEnv in your (apache?) configuration for the database variables and other variables for each domain ([ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html))

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/one-domain.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      onedomain.uk
    DocumentRoot    "/path/to/onedomain/web"
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html
    SetEnv          SYMFONY__GOOGLE__ANALYTICSID mygoogleanalyticsid
    SetEnv          SYMFONY__PAYMENT__APISECRET mysecret
    # ...
    <Directory "/path/to/onedomain/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then use a common parameters.yml setting the variables:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    analytics_id: "google.analyticsid"
    payment_secret: "payment.apisecret"
    # ...
```

They all have their own db settings and any variable you want to set for each.

You can also separate your cache and logs folders, by setting a variable identifying each domain ([ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html)):

```
# app/AppKernel.php
    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        if(getenv("SYMFONY__DOMAIN__NAME")){
            return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment().'/'.getenv("SYMFONY__DOMAIN__NAME");
        } else {
            return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
        }
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        if(getenv("SYMFONY__DOMAIN__NAME")){
            return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs/'.getenv("SYMFONY__DOMAIN__NAME");
        } else {
            return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs/';
        }
    }
```

In case you store sessions in files, you can also do this for the sessions folder:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%/%domain.name%"
```