# Symfony + MongoDB use different database / config parameters depending on routing (and not depending on domain)

Tags: mongodb, symfony

**Abstract : Symfony2 load config depending on route (not on domain)**

I've made a collaborative geo directory open source application ([GoGoCarto](https://github.com/pixelhumain/GoGoCarto)). The application manage users, contributions, administration... ([see one instance of the application](https://presdecheznous.fr/annuaire#/carte/@46.77,5.54,6z?cat=all))

It's made to be re usable, everything is configurable. So everyone can install it on his own server and use it with custom configuration, custom data, custom users...

What I would like to do, is that on the same server, anyone could create his own instance, instead of installing it on different servers.
So from a main website http://gogogocarto.com, I could do http://gogocarto.com/project/test1 or http://gogocarto.com/project/test2 to access to fully separated project "test1" and "test2" (using respectively test1 and test2 database)

What I "just" need to achieve, is using a different mongo database for every instance. The database name is configured in `app/config/config.yml` :

```
doctrine_mongodb:
   default_database: gogocarto
```

I would like to change this value depending on routing.
I already manage to change it depending on subdomain, hacking the doctrine mongodb ODM, but that's not really good because I need to use url like
http://test1.gogocarto.com for it to work. In this case I cannot access "test1" project from a custom redirected domain like http://my-test1.fr or http://dev.test1.fr. And my hack of the mondodb ODM is really ugly...

Thanks for reading me, hope someone would help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: Load config-files depending on domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668734/symfony2-load-config-files-depending-on-domain)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668734/symfony2-load-config-files-depending-on-domain